# C-style for loop in swift 2

Tags: swift, for-loop

XCode is telling me that the following for loop will not compile.  I know that the C-Style Loop was depricated in Swift 3, but I am using Swift 2 on this project, so it should work.

```
for (incrementor = 0; incrementor < someArray.count; incrementor += 1) {
    stuff in the for loop
}
```

Comment: Please know that C style loops have been [deprecated](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md)

Comment: They won't exist in swift 3, but they exist now, and I'm just trying to get them to work currently.

Comment: @GabeSpound - But why use syntax that you know won't work in the future, especially when the modern syntax is so simple and works in both old and new situations?

Comment: put var before incrementor = 0; and then tell what is the issue !

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write a C-Style for loop like this

```
for var i = 1; i <= someArray.count; i += 1 {
  print("i is equal to \(i)")
}
```

You will see warning like below when you write the above code, but as you said you are just testing something so you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: did you miss the paranthesis in your code?

Comment: @AlicanUzun no, in Siwft its upto you that you want to put paranthesis or not.

Answer (score 0):

(Code below should be Swift 2.2 and 3 compatible. Untested as yet though.)

If you want a C-style for loop with an increment, you can use the `stride` method on an integer. For example:

```
for i in 10.stride(through: 50, by: 5) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
for i in stride(from: 10, through: 50, by: 5} {
  ...
}
```

(use `to` instead of `through` if you want "up to, but excluding".)

You can use with the dotted range notation and the `where` statement, if you prefer:

```
for i in 10...50 where i % 5 == 0 {
  ...
}
```

or just replace the whole thing with a while loop:

```
var i = 10
while i <= 50 {
   ...
   i += 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a c-style for loop in the following manner, but it will give you a warning saying that c-style for loops are deprecated. I recommend using the `stride` function or the `where` option in a `for x in y` loop. To use the old style, you can do it like this:

```
for var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1 {
      print("I'm number \(i)")
}
```